# scala type matching for Tuple2

Tags: scala, types, match

I was going through some exercises and noticed the following behavior for matching of tuple2. Is there a particular reason for this?

```
 def test(x: Any): Unit= x match{
  case i: Int => println("int")
  case b: Boolean => println("bool")
  case ti: (_, Int) => println("tuple2 with int")
  case tb: (_, Boolean)=> println("tuple2 with boolean")
  case _ => println("other")
  }                                                

test(false) //prints bool
test(3) ///prints int
test((1,3)) //prints tuple with int
test((1,true)) //prints tuple with int
```

If i exchange the ti and tb cases, then the (1,3) prints tuple2 with boolean. I assume there is some type casting going on here, but I'm unclear why.

Can someone give me a quick explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type erasure. It can't tell what the types are inside the `Tuple` at runtime. It will compile fine, but it should emit a warning. This is what happens when I do it in `:paste` mode in the REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def test(x: Any): Unit= x match{
  case i: Int => println("int")
  case b: Boolean => println("bool")
  case ti: (_, Int) => println("tuple2 with int")
  case tb: (_, Boolean)=> println("tuple2 with boolean")
  case _ => println("other")
  }                                                

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:10: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern (_, Int) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case ti: (_, Int) => println("tuple2 with int")
                  ^
<console>:11: warning: non-variable type argument Boolean in type pattern (_, Boolean) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case tb: (_, Boolean)=> println("tuple2 with boolean")
                  ^
<console>:11: warning: unreachable code
         case tb: (_, Boolean)=> println("tuple2 with boolean")
                                        ^
test: (x: Any)Unit
```

Notice the last warning, it says the `(_, Boolean)` is unreachable because the `(_, Int)` will match on every `Tuple2`, courtesy of type erasure.

Comment: ahh, thank you! For some reason, eclipse didn't emit this warning. I should have known better and tried it out in REPL. Thanks!

Comment: late acceptance...better late than never i guess..sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(x: Any) {
x match {
  case xi: Int => println("int [" + xi + "]")
  case yb: Boolean => println("boolean [" + yb + "]")
  case (x, y @ (y1: Int)) => println("[" + x + ", int(" + y + ")]")
  case (x, y @ (y1: Boolean)) => println("[" + x + ", boolean(" + y + ")]")
  case _ => println("anything else")
}
```

}

```
test(1);
test(true);
test("hello", 1);
test("hello", false);
```

it seems to work this way. 
However, just case (x, y @ Int) doesn't work, even thought it complies.

Comment: mmm interesting. I wonder if the @ then avoids the type erasure mentioned by adelbertc by forcing scala to match on y as well.

Comment: `y @ (y1: Boolean)` can be written as `y @ (_: Boolean)` can be written as `y: Boolean`

Comment: I suppose what is closest to the OP's code is `case ti @ (_, _: Int) => ... `

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works fine with minimal changes to your code. By unpacking and typing, the function works fine.

```
def test: Any => Unit = _ match{
  case i: Int => println("int")
  case b: Boolean => println("bool")
  case (x:Any, y: Boolean)=> println("tuple2 with boolean")
  case (x:Any, y: Int) => println("tuple2 with int")
  case _ => println("other")
}
```